# scope.$eval() is undefined if both input fields have the same directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-validation

I'm trying to validate two password input fields. Simply confirm that they are equal. (*Suggest another approach if mine is way wrong*)

I have implemented a directive with a simple validation that checks if the "confirm" password is the same as the original. But the directive also checks for other things, so I need to have both input fields to have it.

The problem is that when I have my directive on both input fields, I cannot read their model values through the attribute (to check if they match).

Here is a working demo without the directive on the first password:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

});
app.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.mismatch = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        // MAIN CODE:
        return viewValue === scope.$eval(attrs.confirm);
      };

      ctrl.$validators.short = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
          return true;
        }
        if (modelValue.length >= 3) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <form name="form1">
    <input type="password" name="password1" ng-model="pass1"><br>
    <input type="password" my-dir confirm="pass1" name="password2" ng-model="pass2"><br>
    <pre>{{form1.password2.$error | json}}</pre>
    <p ng-show="form1.password2.$error.mismatch" style="color:red">Passwords are different</p>
  </form>

</div>
```

If I change the first filed to:

```
<input type="password" my-dir confirm="pass2" name="password1" ng-model="pass1">
```

to validate in both directions, then `scope.$eval(attrs.confirm)` becomes `undefined` for both fields.

Here is a demo of my issue:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

});
app.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.mismatch = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        // `scope.$eval(attrs.confirm)` always undefined
        return viewValue === scope.$eval(attrs.confirm);
      };

      ctrl.$validators.short = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
          return true;
        }
        if (modelValue.length >= 3) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <form name="form1">
    <input type="password" my-dir confirm="pass2" name="password1" ng-model="pass1"><br>
    <input type="password" my-dir confirm="pass1" name="password2" ng-model="pass2"><br>
    <pre>{{form1.password2.$error | json}}</pre>
    <p ng-show="form1.password2.$error.mismatch || form1.password.$error.mismatch" style="color:red">
      Passwords are different
    </p>
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 2 things:
1. Add `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"` so invalid value will still update scope value.
2. Now you have problem that e.g. changing 2nd input wont trigger 1st re-validation. This is done using observe:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="x = 0; y = 0">
    <form name="form1">
    <input type="password" my-dir="{{y}}" confirm="pass2" name="password1" ng-model="pass1" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"
       ng-change="x = x + 1"><br>
    <input type="password" my-dir="{{x}}" confirm="pass1" name="password2" ng-model="pass2" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"
       ng-change="y = y + 1"><br>
```

and

```
attrs.$observe('myDir', function() {
    ctrl.$validate();
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ws4tVWGXfFNR2yqLRJN7?p=preview

P.S. for usual fields I would write  my-dir="{{pass1}}" and then no need in $eval and ng-change, but for passwords... not sure

Comment: that actually gave me an idea to set up a watcher and use `$setValidity`, instead of using `$validators`. I think I can still check if they match with `return $parse(attrs.confirm)(scope) == ctrl.$modelValue`. But in both my and your solutions, it feels like a hack

Comment: Another way can be: my-dir="{{password1 === password2}}"